# Remove blank and duplicate variables from query string in PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'm looking for a simple function which will remove blank or duplicate variables from a query string in PHP. Take this query string for example:

```
?input=timeline&list=&search=&type=&count=10&keyword=hello&from=&language=en&keyword=&language=en&input=timeline
```

As you can see there are two `input=timeline` and the `language` and `keyword` variables appear twice- once set and once not. Also there are lots of variables that are blank- `list`, `search` and `type`.

What function would clean the URL up to make:

```
?input=timeline&count=10&keyword=hello&from=&language=en
```

?

I've found functions that remove queries, or certain variables, but nothing that comes close to the above- I can't get my head round this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest simply taking advantage of PHP's `parse_str`, but as you mentioned, you've got multiple keys that are the same and `parse_str` will overwrite them simply by the order they're given.

This approach would work to favor values that **are not empty** over values that are, and would **eliminate** keys with empty values:

```
$vars = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

$final = array();

if(!empty($vars)) {
    foreach($vars as $var) {
        $parts = explode('=', $var);

        $key = $parts[0];
        $val = $parts[1];

        if(!array_key_exists($key, $final) && !empty($val))
            $final[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

If your query were `input=value&input=&another=&another=value&final=`, it would yield this array:

```
[input] => value
[another] => value
```

...which you could then form into a valid GET string with `http_build_query($final)`.

Answer (score 3):

`"?" . http_build_query($_GET)` should give you what you want. Since `$_GET` is an associative array any duplicate keys would already be overwritten with the last value supplied in the query string.

Comment: I love the simplicity of this one, but unfortunately it doesn't work for my situation. `http_build_query` does remove duplicates, but if the query was `?test=1&list=hello&list=` the output would be `?test=1&list=` Ideally I want a function that returns the last variable even if a duplicate is blank. Also, http_build_query doesn't remove the blank entries. I need the URL to be as clean as possible. Thanks.

Comment: `http_build_query` simply takes an array or object and turns its keys/properties and their values into a query string-formatted string.